# Can I have PHP send data to a PhoneGap app using Jquery Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cordova

Can I use jquery ajax and call server side php files, return json from those php files, and update controls on the presentation layer of the ios app that I created using phonegap?

I know that a long sentence.

Example,

- Server side php returns json, hello world.
- Normal website uses ajax jquery calls the php, reads returned json,
  populates control on the webpage
- Using phonegap I take this same web app for ios device
- Will it work the same way as it did when it was a web app without
  phonegap making it "native"?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can and as long as you are not doing anything phonegap specific within that process it should work as a web app as well. PhoneGap in a nutshell just wraps your code into an embedded web browser.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, basically you can make it look like a normal webpage, so you will need to make the Ajax call and then use some something to do the  DOM manipulation task.

Take a look at this example using jQuery Mobile:

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36868306/UI%20Development%20using%20jQueryMobile